# Is `--enable-mpbsd` no longer required when building GMP?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, gmp

So I'm trying to build a cross-compiler toolchain off of the latest GCC (`gcc-5.1.0`). GCC requires GMP and so I downloaded GNU MP 6.0 (`gmp-6.0.0`).

Instructions for building GMP suggest (for my purpose) to pass the parameter `--enable-mpbsd` which is [documented as follows](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/jh/chapter06/gmp.html):

> #### The meaning of the new configure options:
>
> `--enable-cxx`
>
> This parameter enables C++ support
>
> `--enable-mpbsd`
>
> This builds the Berkeley MP compatibility library

However, when I fun `configure`, it warns me:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-mpbsd
```

Which suggests that the option was introduced in 5.x and deprecated again in 6.x or replaced by something else ...?!

The exact command line I use is (just for completeness):

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-mpbsd --enable-fft --enable-cxx --host=x86_64-pc-freebsd6
```

**PS:** for now I intend to disregard this warning and proceed anyway. I'll report back whether this still turns out as a functional toolchain.

Comment: The LFS website is wrong, there is no point using `--enable-mpbsd`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: could you elaborate a bit and write this as an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `--enable-mpbsd`
>
> This builds the Berkeley MP compatibility library

This was potentially useful 20 years ago, but it hasn't been for a long time, which is why it was removed from GMP. Linux From Scratch is wrong to recommend the use of that option, it was never required (though it didn't hurt). Please contact them so they can update their instructions.

By the way, you do not need `--enable-shared --enable-static --enable-fft`, they are the default.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. Also the "btw". I decided to go for the `contrib/download_prerequisites` script in the GCC tarball, after all. So no manual build of GMP, MPFR and MPC needed.